# How to scale graph dependent to visible data?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a graph with 7 different DataSet. I can enable and disable them, but how I can scale graph to fit current visible data?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to keep track of the maximum and minumum values of each dataset and try setting the same for respective y axis / x axis maximum and minimum based on the dataset you loaded ?

I had a similar situation where I got data in real time and it could be out of range of my Y axis. So each time i did a check to see if the dynamic data was the new maximum or minimum value in my dataset, lets say it was the new maximum value which was out of the y axis range, I then used `yaxis.setAxisMaximum(maximumValue + paddingValue)`, to make sure the point appeared on the chart and was in range. You could make use of a similar strategy. Hope this helps and was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Padding value in this context?
or how can I get Y axis intervals?

In my app I'm creating a line graph (out of some dynamic data), and I need the y max value to be visible.

My max value is 109 but my grph max Y axis label is up to 100 only.How can I show the next entry too
[image]

Regards
Divya